# How would you say "it's your turn" in a game?

Tags: demande-de-mot

Google Translate gives *C'est ton tour.* Is this what you would use, when telling a friend it's his turn in a game? To give an example, I'm playing a friend in Words with Friends (a lot like Scrabble) and I would like to say to him, "It's your turn".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a couple of common ways to say it:

> - *[C'est] à toi*
> - *C'est à ton tour [de jouer]*

Dropping the *à* is possible too:

> - *C'est ton tour*

Here is, as I discovered thanks to your very question, quite a localized one:

> - *Ça vient à toi* (Marseille area only!)

To answer to your first comment, note that *à mon/ton/son tour* is an old "set expression".

Quoted from: *Curiositez françoises pour supplément aux dictionnaires* Antoine Oudin, 1640

> [*C'est à son tour : C'est à luy à faire, son temps est venu.*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k50817x/f550.image)

Comment: I must say, I'm a little surprised by the preposition à. I would have thought that *C'est ton tour* would be correct. Could you explain the need for this preposition?

Comment: @ktm5124 The "à son tour" is a fixed expression. I'd say, for instance: « À ce rythme, ce ne sera qu’une question de temps avant que Sophie ne soit larguée **à son tour**. » === "Now, it's **her turn** to be ditched."

Comment: @Alone-zee Expression fixe. Je comprends. Merci.

Comment: "Ça vient à toi" is something I have never heard. Could this be a regional turn of phrase ?

Comment: @Greg You are right. Thanks! I never noticed it before but this is typical from Marseille / Provence (possibly wider Occitan area).

Comment: @jlliagre: I've never heard this one around Toulouse. Unless the situation makes it very obvious, I don't think I would have understood this actually.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Bouducon ! Je ne trouve pas de références ailleurs que dans le 13 ! C'est vraiment du parler marseillais et je ne m'en étais jamais rendu compte.

Comment: The revised version of the answer might make the impression that « *à ton tour* » is no longer normally used… A new correction necessary? Or that was exactly the impression you were willing to make?

Comment: @Evgeniy Yes, answer revised to clarify *à ton tour* usage. Thanks!

Comment: Ce n'est pas écrit dans les réponses possibles mais personnellement j'utilise "*À toi*" dans 99% des cas (que je vois comme la contraction de "*À toi de jouer*".

Comment: Je suis marseillais et je confirme que je dis "Ça vient à toi" :)

Answer (score 5):

How you tell your friend it is his turn to play depends how close you are and how formal you want to be.  From very formal to complete slang:

- *C'est à vous, chère amie!*
- *C'est ton tour!*
- *À toi de jouer!*
- *À toi!*
- *Quand tu veux, mon neveu!*
- *Z-y-va, pose tes tuiles!*

Answer (score 3):

I was playing bridge online with a couple from Canada this morning, and they used "tu joues".